# Detecting network state (connected - disconnected) in C#

Tags: c#, compact-framework, networking, windows-ce, ethernet

I am in need of a piece of code that can detect if a network connection is connected or disconnected. The connected state would mean a cable was plugged into the Ethernet connection. A disconnected state would mean there is not cable connected.

I can't use the WMI interface due to the fact that I'm running on Windows CE. I don't mind invoking the Win32 API but remember that I'm using Windows CE and running on the Compact Framework.

Comment: One thing to remember is that a network connection is not equal to an internet connection.

It sounds like you already get that because you define connected as meaning "a cable is plugged into the Ethernet connection", but it bears repeating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this MSDN article:

[Testing for and Responding to Network Connections in the .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446548.aspx)

Comment: The "solution" the link points to will not detect whether a cable is present of not - it detects whether a host is reachable.  As Joel points out, those are two totally different things.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use [OpenNETCF's SDF](http://opennetcf.codeplex.com) and look at the [OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceWatcher class](http://opennetcf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OpenNETCF.Net/OpenNETCF.Net/NetworkInformation/NetworkInterfaceWatcher.cs), which will raise events when NDIS sends out notifications  (like MEDIA_CONNECT and MEDIA_DISCONNECT).

You can do the same work without the SDF, of course.  It involves onening the NDIS driver directly and calling [IOCTL_NDISUIO_REQUEST_NOTIFICATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924905.aspx) with a P2P message queue handle.  It's not overly difficult, but there's a lot you have to get right for it to work and not leak.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded 2.3 binaries from https://opennetcf.codeplex.com/releases/view/137461 but I can't find the AdapterStatusMonitor in OpenNETCF.Net Namespace... Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the `NetworkInterfaceWatcher` http://opennetcf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OpenNETCF.Net/OpenNETCF.Net/NetworkInformation/NetworkInterfaceWatcher.cs

Answer (score 1):

Call [GetAdaptersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916102.aspx) and loop through the list of available network adapters until you find the one you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember is that a network connection is **not** equal to an internet connection.

It sounds like you already get that because you define connected as meaning "a cable is plugged into the Ethernet connection", but it bears repeating.

Comment: Yeah, I understand this. I really want to just detect the "cable" connection state.

Comment: @kelton52 Agree. The rules have changed since June of 2009 :) I've added the comment, and I'll delete this in a few minutes.