# using System.Net.NetworkInformation errors

Tags: networking, compact-framework

I want to use NetworkInformation namespace and when I use system.net.networkInformation I'm getting error: "The type or namespace name 'NetworkInformation' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?) "

I'm compact framework v2.0 or 3.5. compact framework should support networkInformation namespace?

I also tried to use this code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "ipconfig.exe";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
return output;
```

but the StandartOutput and redirectStandartoutput doesn't exist.

I'm trying to find out is the LAN is up or down. There is other way that I can use with compact framework?

Comment: The `Compact-Framework` only has a small subset of the full framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [OpenNetCF's Smart Device Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx). I've used classes in this framework on several occasions when I find they are missing from CF2.0

See @ctacke's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936027/detecting-network-state-connected-disconnected-in-c-sharp):

> The easiest way is to use OpenNETCF's SDF and look at the
>   OpenNETCF.Net.AdapterStatusMonitor class, which will raise events when
>   NDIS sends out notifications (like MEDIA_CONNECT and
>   MEDIA_DISCONNECT).

Comment: I'm getting the exception: PublicKeyToken= ... or one of it's dependencies, was not found."
I downloaded the dll but I can't find the license.
what should I do?

Comment: I'm getting the exception:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' occurred in OpenNETCF.Net.dll

Additional information: Connection Manager API is not supported under this platform.

I need to add to the SDK this dlls?